# Insert mode <S-Tab> to delete one <Tab>-indent?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, lua

I want to use `<S-Tab>` to do the reverse of `<Tab>` in insert mode in Lua. (If this is complicated in Lua then VimScript is OK) How?

Answer (score 1):

Is `<C-d>` what you want? `:h i_CTRL-D`

```
                        *i_CTRL-D*
CTRL-D      Delete one shiftwidth of indent at the start of the current
        line.  The indent is always rounded to a 'shiftwidth' (this is
        vi compatible).
```

If so

```
inoremap <S-Tab> <C-d>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<S-Tab>', "v:lua.check_back_space() ? '<BS>' : '<NOP>'", EXPR_NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC)
```

where `EXPR_...` is

```
local EXPR_NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC = { expr = true, noremap = true, silent = true, nowait = true }
```

and `check_back_space` can be implemented easily.